# Control speed of brushless DC motor

Tags: dc-motor

Assuming I have a brushless DC motor which externally exposes only a + and - terminal. (I.e. I do not have access to the windings and hall sensor directly.)

Is there a way to control the speed? With a brushed DC motor one could just reduce the supply voltage.

Am I correct in assuming that this is not really an option for a brushless DC motor that will give a lot of range? I am thinking that most likely the internal commutation control circuit is powered using a voltage divider: if one reduced the supply voltage, the internal control circuit would experience low voltage dropout, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the motor.  Here are three cases I've seen.

(1) Generate a rather slow PWM signal. I used 100Hz.  It was a small fan and it varied speed rather nicely.

(2) Fans with lots of smarts inside (I tore one apart and there was a Microchip PIC in there).  It had a power-up delay of 100-200 milliseconds.  That means that when your operating frequency approaches 5-10 Hz, the fan is off 100% percent of the time (it never completes the power-on).  You can run pulses around 5 Hz or less, but it sounds ridiculous and you don't get much control.

(3) I put a big capacitor across the output in an attempt to convert the output pulses to an average dc level.  Fan had an internal commutation circuit alright, and when I reduced the voltage, it would draw more current in an attempt to keep going the same speed!  So you couldn't really control it that way, either.

Comment: Thanks for this. For case (1), how noticeable was the PWM acoustically?

Comment: As I recall, there was no noticeable 100Hz noise.  It was a low power fan, though.  Expect results to vary with fan type.